# Trying to install GeoFire through Cocoapods, but getting Objective-C Module error

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, geofire

So there is an odd build issue I’m encountering.

I have an existing Xcode project where all my packages have been added through Xcode itself (I think Xcode basically uses Swift Package Manager underneath).

I came to a point where I needed to now use `GeoFire` . But Geofire needs to be installed through Cocoapods. But my Xcode project never used cocoapods.

So to integrate Cocoapods I did the following:

1. `brew install cocoapods`
2. opened terminal and navigated to root directory of iOS app (where `<app-name>.xcodeproj` exists)
3. `pod init`
4. opened the generated Podfile and added the following:
   …
   `platform :ios, '11.0’`
   …
   `pod 'GeoFire', '~> 4.0’`
   …
5. `pod install`
6. opened `<app-name>.xcworkspace`
7. Then when I went to build the project, the following failure occurred (see image attached to question)
   [image]

None of the workarounds suggested have helped me thus far. Any thoughts?

NOTE: I am doing all this on an M1 Macbook.

Comment: Did you opened the xcworkspace afterwards?

Comment: Yup. I opened xcworkspace specifically.
I even tried the method were you delete the DerivedData folder and rerun `pod install`. Still fixed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, strange issue.
What ended up fixing it for me was to go to my pod file and replace:
`pod 'GeoFire', '~> 4.0'`

With:
`pod 'GeoFire/Utils'`

Now I can use GeoFire in my file as I wish.